# js slideToggle() makes my element at the bottom of div appear first

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qm9wpsy8/) because I don't really know how to explain it easily.

As you can see when you press the `btn` the `h2` tag appears pretty much onclick and it makes the slidetoggle pretty much obsolete.

Anyone know how to get the `h2` to appear only after the animation is done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it display none, then fade it in after a delay. The example below isn't perfect, but you will get the idea =)

//Javasript

```
$("#menu").hide();
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#btn').length) {
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
        $( "#heading" ).delay( 1200 ).fadeIn( 400 );

    } else if (!$(e.target).closest('#notepad').length) {
        $('#menu').slideUp();
    }
});
```

//CSS

```
h2 {
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

//HTML

```
<div id="item">
    <div id="menu">
        <h1>Some content here...</h1>
        <h2 id="heading">Bottom of div</h2>
    </div>
    <p id="btn">Click Me!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `position: relative` to `#menu`

Comment: Well notice how the `h2` tag appears on click and it makes the effect look really bad. http://jsfiddle.net/qm9wpsy8/1/

Comment: This is because you're setting `bottom: 0` to the `h2` element. If you think about it, it's working properly... it's always being placed at the bottom of the parent element. Now, try changing it to `top: XXpx` instead. You'll see that it sticks relative to the TOP of the parent element.